# Mongodb see if all items in array exist and update else insert

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose

I have a mongo collection of tags and when the user enters an array of tags I want to do the following :

If a tag in the array exists, update the count
If a tag in the array does not exist, insert with a count of 0

I currently have :

```
QuestionTags.update({'tag': {$in: tagArray}}, {$inc : {'count': +1} }, { upsert: true });
```

`QuestionTags` is the mongoose schema for the db collection.

This does not seem to be working. I entered an array of new tags and they are not being added, and the existing tags are not being incremented.

Is there a way to handle this without having to loop through `tagArray` and make a db call for each item in the array?

UPDATE: 
Changed my code to this

```
QuestionTags.update({'tag': {$in: req.body.tags}}, {$inc : {'count': +1} }, { upsert: true, multi: true });
QuestionTags.find({'tag' :{$nin: req.body.tags}}, function(err, newTags) {
    console.log("New Tags :" + newTags);
    var tagArray = [];
    newTags.forEach(function(tag){
        var tagObj = {
            tag: tag,
            count: 1
        }
        tagArray.push(tagObj);
    });
    QuestionTags.collection.insert(tagArray);
});
```

However, `newTags` is null. QuestionTags collection is currently empty so it should not be null.

Comment: What is in your tagArray ? simple strings ? I just did a test, and incrementing works with your update query. For inserting, you don't have a `$set: {tag: 'newTag'}` in your update object (2nd parameter of update), so the upsert is not actually inserting anything.

Comment: @Komo yeah its just simple strings ["Java", "JavaScript", "Agile"]. If everything else is working, you can post a solution with the correct way to do it

Comment: @Komo did the solution you posted not work?

Comment: sadly no, I think there is no way to "filter" an array by querying mongo without doing a loop

Comment: I posted a new answer which I hope will suit you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you can do this in a few queries, without querying in a loop.

1) Update existing tags count : your query works :

```
QuestionTags.update({'tag': {$in: tagArray}}, {$inc : {'count': +1} },{multi: true} );
```

2) Find new tags :

```
QuestionTags.find({},function(err, tags) {
    var newTagObj = [];

    // tags is originally an array of objects
    // creates an array of strings (just tag name)
    tags = tags.map(function(tag) {
        return tag.tag;
    });

    // returns tags that do not exist
    var newTags = tagArray.filter(function(tag) {
        // The count = 1 can be done here
        if (tags.indexOf(tag) < 0) {
            tag.count = 1;
        }

        return tags.indexOf(tag) < 0;
    });

    // creates tag objects with a count of 1
    // adds to array
    // (this can be done in the previous loop)
    newTags.forEach(function(tag) {
        var tagObj = {
            tag: tag,
            count: 1
        }
        newTagObj.push(tagObj);
    });
```

This will give you an array of tags that don't exist in database.

3) Insert new tags using result of 2, in the `find` callback:

```
QuestionTags.collection.insertMany(newTagObj);
```

Comment: Overall this works pretty well. However, the count doesn't seem to be updating. It is just inserting new records every time even when the tags have the same 'tag' attribute.

Comment: Hmm, did you remove the upsert option in the update query ? It shouldn't add new records, at least.

Comment: Yeah the update query is identical to that. Not sure why it's not working. I logged out tagArray before the update, before the filter, and then new tags and they all contain the same items

Comment: That's strange, maybe you can run a find in your mongo terminal `db.QuestionTags.find({ tag: { $in: ['tag1','tag2'] } })` to see if the query object of the update query actually finds something

Comment: yeah that returns me back all the rows

Comment: Can you post the query you ran and the full results it gave you please ?

Comment: I fixed some issues with the code. Everything is updating correctly now. However, the indexOf does not work which is why everything is saving. Currently trying to resolve that

Comment: I should have mentioned that, but IndexOf will work if both arrays contains only strings, if the array returned from database contains Objects (like it should), you will have to create a new array contains strings: `tags = tags.map(function (tag) { return tag.tag })`

Comment: I have a complete solution. Do you want me to edit yours?

Comment: updated. please review and accept changes. thanks for working through that with me

Comment: Cool, glad it worked out. I added a little improvement so you can gain a loop.